# React state resets/behaves badly when changing rapidly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Here I have a timer minute state and a scroll container, where the state value changes based on the scroll position and vice versa:

```
const Container = ({ minutes, setMinutes}) => {

draggableElement = useRef(null);

const handleScroll = () => {
const scrollableWidth =
      draggableElement.current.container.current.scrollWidth -
      draggableElement.current.container.current.offsetWidth;

    const amountScrolled = draggableElement.current.scrollLeft;
    const rangeValue = (amountScrolled / scrollableWidth) * 30;

    setMinutes(Math.round(rangeValue));

}
 useEffect(() => {
    draggableElement.current.container.current.scrollLeft = minutes * 20;
  }, [minutes]);

 return (
    <ScrollContainer
      className="container"
      ref={draggableElement}
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      id="scrolling-container"
      vertical={false}
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(100, 0.25em)",
        //border: "1px solid yellow",
        width: "4em",
        height: "50%",
        alignItems: "center",
        cursor: "grab",
        marginBottom: "1rem",
      }}
    >
      <Tick >1</Tick>
      <Tick >2</Tick>
      <Tick >3</Tick>
      <Tick >4</Tick>
      <Tick >5</Tick>
      //more ticks here

 </ScrollContainer>
);
};
```

on top of that, I also have counter buttons where you can increase/decrease the minute state value:

```
<AddButton onClick={()=> setMinutes(minutes + 1)}></AddButton>
<SubtractButton onClick={()=> setMinutes(minutes - 1)}></SubtractButton>
```

Now, everything seemed to be working just fine, until I tried to rapidly click the `AddButton`/`SubtractButton`. I have observed the following problems:

1. If I rapidly click it without using the scroll container yet, the state becomes **NaN**.
2. If I rapidly click it after scrolling to a specific position, the state value resets to the value based on the scroll position. *Example: I scroll to position value 3, state value becomes 3. I click `AddButton` rapidly, state becomes 4 for a split second then resets to 3.*

As I mentioned before, it works just fine if I click at a slow pace. Also, scrolling rapidly doesn't cause any problems.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When modifying a state based on its previous value, it's better to use this pattern to avoid race conditions: `setMinutes(m => m + 1)`

Comment: Just did `setMinutes(m => m + 1)`, nonetheless, the problem still persists

Comment: It would be worth including where you are defining the state, it sounds like it might be being used before a value is set.